# Combinatorial proof of ${2n \choose 3} = 2 \times {n \choose 3} + 2 \times {n \choose 1}{n\choose 2}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, combinations

I need to prove ${2n \choose 3} = 2 \times {n \choose 3} + 2 \times {n \choose 1}{n\choose 2}$ forming my
counting problem as such:

Suppose that we are trying to count the number of ways
to form a sports team of (insert the correct number here) students picked from (complete the rest of
this sentence, being very precise/specific).

I am entirely new to binomials and any help for where to begin or general guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: The left hand side is the number of ways choose a team of 3 people from a group of 2n people.  Split that group into two haves with n people in each. See if you can interpret the RHS in the light of this.

Comment: Suppose we had $n$ boys and $n$ girls.  What might $\binom{2n}{3}$ count in this scenario?  What might $\binom{n}{3}$ count in this scenario?  Recall that $\binom{a}{b}$ is used for counting things like the number of subsets of size $b$ from a set of size $a$.

Comment: Use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Combinatorial_proof) combinatorial proof with $m=n,\,r=3$. It helps to write your RHS as$$\binom{n}{0}\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{1}\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{2}\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{3}\binom{n}{0}.$$

Comment: The punchline at the end of the day for problems like these is that if we have a scenario we wish to count and if there are multiple different approaches that we could take to count it... so long as each of the approaches we took was correct then even if the answers appear different among the different approaches we know that they must be equal regardless, the so-called [Principle of Double Counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(proof_technique)).

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(proof_technique)) is the punchline @JMoravitz mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have total of $2n$ players of which $n$ are experienced and $n$ are new.

You are making a team of $3$ pplayers by choosing $3$ out of $2n$ players - which is $2n \choose 3$.

The selection of $3$ will contain either i) All $3$ experienced ii) All $3$ new iii) $2$ new, $1$ experienced and iv) $1$ new and $2$ experienced.

If we add selection for all of these cases, it should equal to $2n \choose 3$.

So ${2n \choose 3} = {n \choose 3} + {n \choose 3} + {n \choose 1} {n \choose 2} + {n \choose 2} {n \choose 1} = 2 {n \choose 3} + 2 {n \choose 1} {n \choose 2}$

Answer (score 1):

Say we have red and blue line, each containig $n$ points. How many triples can we choose?

- First answer is ${2n\choose 3}$
- Second we can choose 3 points from one line so that is ${n\choose 3}$ triples times 2 and we can choose 2 points fome one line and 1 point from other, so that is ${n\choose 2}{n\choose 1}$ times 2.